# Using gsub conditionally based on numbers and not patterns

Tags: regex, gsub

is it possible to use `gsub` depending on a condition based on a digit, instead of a pattern?

As an example:

```
A      B
3      2
5      1
6      7
2      8
4      2
```

Imagine that I want to transform, in column A, numbers higher than 4 to the character `high`; while those lower or equal to 4 to the character `low`:

```
A      B
low    2
high   1
high   7
low    8
low    2
```

I would like to use something like:

```
df$A<-c(sapply(df$A, function(x) gsub(????, ??, x)))
```

Comment: You do not need `gsub` here. Use `df$A <- ifelse(df$A>4, "high", "low")`

Comment: and do you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an `ifelse` here:

```
A <- c(3,5,6,2,4)
B <- c(2,1,7,8,2)

df <- data.frame(A,B)
df$A <- ifelse(df$A>4, "high", "low")
df
```

Output:

```
     A B
1  low 2
2 high 1
3 high 7
4  low 8
5  low 2
```

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##K/r/31HBRlchWcNYx1THTMdIx0STywkiYqRjqGOuY6FjpMnFlZIGEktJLEnUSytKzE3VcNRx0gSKqoB1Z6al5hSnaoC4diY6CkoZmekZSkA6J79cCaTq/38A)

Comment: and how would you do this if I wanted to divide 3 groups instead of 2? For example, if I expected: `high` for `> 5`; `mid` for `>3 <=5` and `low` for `<=3`?

Comment: @Jeni `ifelse` [will still work](https://tio.run/##TczRCsIgGAXge5/iQJET/oI0V9A22N5EcjZha2BBj286b7o8H@ecEGOP5ohHpUhTTZIugg1FJJ3pSjeSgjHrslnzMScXzDJWPQ0i6X5bezfO77HKsVM4oHgLTeCLt5z@G@g2n/xz4sTn9csF8hVjO2SEW0Pu3JGmJah0pmFeFqm@UdOqGH8): `df$A <- ifelse(df$A>3 & df$A <= 5, 'mid', ifelse(df$A > 5, 'high','low') )`